# compare 2 excel sheets for differences

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare 2 excel sheets (Sheet1 (old report) & Sheet2 (new report)) for differences. If there are any additions or removals in Sheet2 compared to Sheet1 I need to print that.

I found this script to find the differences but this is not including the removals in the sheet. Can you help fixing this? Below is sample example on my expectation.

**Sheet1:**

S.No Name   Class

1. abc1   1st
2. abc2   1st
3. abc3   1st

**Sheet2:**

S.No Name   Class

1. abc1   1st
2. abc2   2nd
3. abc4   1st

.

**Comparison should tell all these:**

"Row(3,3)" is changed from "1st" to "2nd"

New row inserted in "sheet2" "Row4"

"Sheet1" "Row4" is deleted in "Sheet2"

---

**Script currently I have:**

```
Sub Compare2Shts()
For Each cell In Worksheets("CompareSheet#1").UsedRange
If cell.Value <> Worksheets("CompareSheet#2").Range(cell.Address) Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("CompareSheet#2").UsedRange
If cell.Value <> Worksheets("CompareSheet#1").Range(cell.Address) Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next
End Sub


Sub CompareAnother2Shts()
For Each cell In Worksheets("CompareSheet#1").Range("A1:J50000")
If cell.Value <> Worksheets("CompareSheet#2").Range(cell.Address) Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("CompareSheet#2").Range("A1:J50000")
If cell.Value <> Worksheets("CompareSheet#1").Range(cell.Address) Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next
End Sub


Sub FindDupes() 'assuming both sheets are in same book and book is open
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim str As String
    str = InputBox("Type name of first sheet")
    Set sht1 = Worksheets(str)
    str = InputBox("Type name of second sheet")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets(str)


    sht1.Range("A65536").End(xlDown).Activate
    Selection.End(xlUp).Activate
    LastRowSht1 = ActiveCell.Row

    sht2.Activate
    sht2.Range("A65536").End(xlDown).Activate
    Selection.End(xlUp).Activate
    LastRowSht2 = ActiveCell.Row

    sht1.Activate
    For rowSht1 = 1 To LastRowSht1
        If sht1.Cells(rowSht1, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub
        For rowSht2 = 1 To LastRowSht2
            If sht1.Cells(rowSht1, 1).Value = sht2.Cells(rowSht2, 1).Value Then
                sht1.Cells(rowSht1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                sht2.Cells(rowSht2, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

            End If
        Next
    Next
    sht1.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********

Sub checkrev()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Sh1LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh1Range = .Range("A1:A" & Sh1LastRow)
End With
With Sheets("Sheet2")
Sh2LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh2Range = .Range("A1:A" & Sh2LastRow)
End With

'compare sheet 1 with sheet 2
For Each Sh1cell In Sh1Range
Set c = Sh2Range.Find( _
what:=Sh1cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
Sh1cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
If Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1) <> c.Offset(0, 1) Then
Sh1cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
End If
Next Sh1cell
'compare sheet 2 with sheet 1
For Each Sh2cell In Sh2Range
Set c = Sh1Range.Find( _
what:=Sh2cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
Sh2cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
If Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1) <> c.Offset(0, 1) Then
Sh2cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
End If
Next Sh2cell

End Sub

********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********

Sub TestCompareWorksheets()
    ' compare two different worksheets in the active workbook
    CompareWorksheets Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' compare two different worksheets in two different workbooks
'    CompareWorksheets ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), _
        Workbooks("WorkBookName.xls").Worksheets("Sheet2")
End Sub



Sub CompareWorksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
Dim r As Long, c As Integer
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc1 As Integer, lc2 As Integer
Dim maxR As Long, maxC As Integer, cf1 As String, cf2 As String
Dim rptWB As Workbook, DiffCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Creating the report..."
    Set rptWB = Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    While Worksheets.Count > 1
        Worksheets(2).Delete
    Wend
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    With ws1.UsedRange
        lr1 = .Rows.Count
        lc1 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    With ws2.UsedRange
        lr2 = .Rows.Count
        lc2 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    maxR = lr1
    maxC = lc1
    If maxR < lr2 Then maxR = lr2
    If maxC < lc2 Then maxC = lc2
    DiffCount = 0
    For c = 1 To maxC
        Application.StatusBar = "Comparing cells " & Format(c / maxC, "0 %") & "..."
        For r = 1 To maxR
            cf1 = ""
            cf2 = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            cf1 = ws1.Cells(r, c).FormulaLocal
            cf2 = ws2.Cells(r, c).FormulaLocal
            On Error GoTo 0
            If cf1 <> cf2 Then
                DiffCount = DiffCount + 1
                Cells(r, c).Formula = "'" & cf1 & " <> " & cf2
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
    Application.StatusBar = "Formatting the report..."
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(maxR, maxC))
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Columns("A:IV").ColumnWidth = 20
    rptWB.Saved = True
    If DiffCount = 0 Then
        rptWB.Close False
    End If
    Set rptWB = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox DiffCount & " cells contain different formulas!", vbInformation, _
        "Compare " & ws1.Name & " with " & ws2.Name
End Sub

********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********

Sub Match()

r1 = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
r2 = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set r3 = Worksheets("sheet1")
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2").Select
For a = 2 To r2
For i = 2 To r1
If Cells(a, "A") = r3.Cells(i, "A") Then
temp = r3.Cells(i, "B")
te = te & "," & temp
Else
End If
Next i
Cells(a, "B") = te
te = ""
Next a
End Sub


Sub Match2()
Dim myCon As String
Dim myCell As Range
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Sheet2.Range("A2:A10")
myCon = ""
For Each myCell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A15")
If cell = myCell Then
If myCon = "" Then
myCon = myCell.Offset(0, 1)
Else
myCon = myCon & ", " & myCell.Offset(0, 1)
End If
End If
Next myCell
cell.Offset(0, 1) = myCon
Next cell
End Sub

********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********

Sub Duplicates()
ScreenUpdating = False

'get first empty row of sheet1

'find matching rows in sheet 2
With Sheets("Masterfile")
RowCount = 1
Do While .Range("A" & RowCount) <> ""
ID = Trim(.Range("A" & RowCount))
'compare - look for ID in Sheet 2
With Sheets("List")
Set c = .Columns("A").Find(what:=ID, _
LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
End With
If c Is Nothing Then
.Range("B" & RowCount) = "No"
Else
.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Yes"
End If

RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop
End With

ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for the elaborate post. Yet, I was unable to see the immanent question within. Could you please help me? Is the code working or not? If it is not working then please elaborate on the error messages that you get. If your code is incomplete and requires more code to accomplish additional tasks then you're probably in the wrong place as this site does not offer free code-writing services. If you have working code which requires merely tweaking then you should try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). So, which one is it? Thanks.

Comment: The above is working fine and displaying the differences.

But my ask is it should also highlight if new new rows are added in the sheet 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have looks overly complex.

For a non-vba solution, see below.

Sheet 1 formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,0)),"Removed",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,0)=B2,"Same","Changed to: " &VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,0)))
```

[image]

Sheet 2 formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4,2,0)),"Added",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4,2,0)=B2,"Same","Changed"))
```

[image]

I realize I may haved simplified things a bit, but you can adjust wording and whatever is needed. You can also apply conditional formatting as needed.